# If I have a JSON data, how do I return an array of JSON file?

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

I have a JSON file formated like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 2011136021,
    tree_level: 3,
    main_category_id: 105,
    sub_nodes: [
      128001,
      128002,
      128003,
      2011136046
    ],
  }
]
```

I want to return the value of `sub_nodes` based on the parent ID 2011136046:

```
sub_nodes: [
  128001,
  128002,
  128003,
  2011136046
],
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: That's invalid JSON, bru.

Comment: i think this might help {
id: 2011136021,
tree_level: 3,
main_category_id: 105,
sub_nodes: [
128001,
128002,
128003,
2011136046
],},

Comment: I think this can help :   [{"id":2011136021,"tree_level":3,"main_category_id":105,"sub_nodes":[128001,128002,128003,2011136046],"attributes":{"@id":"2011136021","@uri":"/api/metadata/category/2011136021","level":"SHOW","levelTypeId":6,"parent":{"@id":"126","@uri":"/api/web/category/126","articles":"","metadata":{"@uri":"/api/metadata/category/126"},"categories":{"@uri":"/api/web/category/126/categories"},"available":false},"parentId":126,"priority":1,"properties":"","title":"Moods of Norway"

Answer (score 3):

For just one second, let's pretend you have valid JSON

```
require "json"

json = '{"id":2011136021,"tree_level":3,"main_category_id":105,"sub_nodes":[128001,128002,128003,2011136046]}'

obj = JSON.parse(json)
# => {"id"=>2011136021, "tree_level"=>3, "main_category_id"=>105, "sub_nodes"=>[128001, 128002, 128003, 2011136046]}

sub_nodes = obj["sub_nodes"]
# => [128001, 128002, 128003, 2011136046]
```

If you want to convert `sub_nodes` back to JSON

```
JSON.generate(sub_nodes)
# => "[128001,128002,128003,2011136046]"
```

But now we can stop pretending since you don't have valid JSON.

Comment: it says "can't convert Array into String" any idea?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Look at the JSON in my answer. Just, never mind.

Comment: This is what i have got, i used JSONVIEW chrome extension {
id: 2011136021,
tree_level: 3,
main_category_id: 105,
sub_nodes: [
128001,
128002,
128003,
2011136046
],
attributes: {}
},]

Comment: Right, and what you just pasted is not valid JSON. Read the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) for more details.

Comment: is this the correct format you are looking for? [{"id":2011136021,"tree_level":3,"main_category_id":105,"sub_nodes":[128001,128002,128003,2011136046],"attributes":{"@id":"2011136021","@uri":"/api/metadata/category/2011136021","level":"SHOW","levelTypeId":6,"parent":{"@id":"126","@uri":"/api/web/category/126","articles":"","metadata":{"@uri":"/api/metadata/category/126"},"categories":{"@uri":"/api/web/category/126/categories"},"available":false},"parentId":126,"priority":1,"properties":"","title":"Moods of Norway"

Comment: That's not JSON. Again, refer to the [JSON spec](http://json.org/) for more help. JSON is a **string**; not an **array** or any other data type. The JSON I used in my answers is valid JSON that's pretty close to your original data structure.